# Eclipse doesn't start

Tags: eclipse, windows-7-x64

I'm using eclipse 3.6 on windows 7 x64 and out of nowhere it failed starting one day. I see in the task manager that it begins and crashes after a second. No error message, nothing. I also extracted the files of eclipse again from the zip, and the problem is still there. 
It starts though through windows troubleshoot compatibility. What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: **May be it's time to download new version** !!!

Comment: you can try to reinstall it, you will not lose your workspace by doing so

Comment: Try to launch it from java: `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar`. What happens in this case?

Comment: Check if you get new or updated log files in your eclipse directory, and post them if so.

Comment: There may be a message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory or in the installation 'configuration' directory.

Comment: ... and if all else fails, create a new workspace and re-import all projects. This is a major buggerance, but you could see it as part of an upgrade path.

Comment: What happens when you try and run a version of Eclipse released in the last 5 years?

Comment: launching from java doesn't work

Comment: I've found an error file in the configuration directory! But I don;t understand it.."!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-14 11:55:55.190
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (178).
!STACK 0"